# No vertical scrollbar visible in select 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select 2 4.0.6-rc.0 with bootstrap 4.3

```
<div class="row option-select">
      <div class="col-sm-6 country-col">
      <select id="selection" class="custom-select custom-select-sm">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am fetching the data via ajax. Everything is working fine except that the select shows 5 options and there is no scrollbar so i cannot view more options even though there are more than 10.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#selection').select2({

        ajax: {
          url: './data/c-list.php',
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 250,
          data: function (params) {
            return {
              searchTerm: params.term
            };
          },
          processResults: function(response) {
            return {
              results: response
            };
          },
          cache: true
        }
});

});
```